# Null Error when checking null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, session-variables, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to test values before doing some actions with session variables.
This is for initializing( As you can see **Session("Chemin") is a List of String**:

```
        @If (IsDBNull(Session("Chemin")) Or (ViewContext.RouteData.Values("action") = "Index")) Then
        @Code Dim lst As New List(Of String)()
        Session("Chemin") = lst  // Initialisation
     End Code
End If
```

But the problem is with the test here  :

```
@If (Not IsDBNull(ViewContext.RouteData.Values("action")) AndAlso Not IsDBNull(Session("Chemin")) AndAlso Not Session("Chemin").Contains((ViewContext.RouteData.Values("action").ToString()))) Then
```

I sometimes get

> System.NullReferenceException

I don't understand because I am just testing it, and yet it throws me an error.
So my question is : Why and when exactly does it happens ? How to fix this ?
Edit: not a duplicate because not a simple System.NullReferenceException

Comment: try changing it to 
`ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("action");`

Comment: ToString can't return System.DbNull which is what IsDbNull is comparing it to, your evaluation there will always return false.

Comment: Esko, It's the same without ToString I put it there because I was desperate, I was using it later . By I agree it was dumb

Comment: Shashank, I get the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: why are you using IsDBNull? if the session value is a string use String.isnullorempty

Comment: If there always a value in Session("Chemin")? If not you should check it before trying to use it.

Comment: Try if (Session("Chenin") = Nothing instead of dbnull

Comment: See the section "DBNull is not the same as Nothing" at the selected answer on the duplicate target.  Also, take note of the instructions on how to debug your error.  A NRE is trivial to fix, and you should learn immediately how to track it down and avoid it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace all your `IsDBNull` with `IsNothing`, that is what you are looking for in this case. Because I think your

```
    @If (IsDBNull(Session("Chemin"))
```

could not pass and so the Session("Chemin") could be Nothing.

You should check that `ViewContext`, `ViewContext.RouteData` , `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` and `ViewContext.RouteData.Values("action")` are not nothing just in case.

You can do it with this :

```
                                                @Code Dim values = ViewContext?.RouteData?.Values End Code
                                        @If (values IsNot Nothing) // And the rest of your tests
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** DbNull is not the same as null (which is `Nothing` in VB slang). So you should check whether that method `IsDbNull()` crashes if you call it like this: `IsDbNull(Nothing)`.
I think so, but I'm not sure. If so, add that additional null-check and you're good.

If the problem is still present, lets dive deeper:

Is an expression like `ViewContext.RouteData.Values("action")` all the properties in the chain could be null. This means if `ViewContext`, `RouteData` or even the `Values` are null, this exception will be thrown.

The same for the `Session` itself: it is a kind of value container and you check whether a value at a given key **in that container** is null. But what if the `Session` itself is null? The same applies to the `Values` property as well.

Basically this would translate to `null.ElementAt("Chemin")`. And that will crash before the surrounding `IsDbNull()` gets called.

So you might check like this:

```
Session Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Session("Chemin"))
' note: you might want to check if the session contains the key before getting a value with it
```

And

```
Dim values = ViewContext?.RouteData?.Values ' see "Elvis Operator" for the question marks
If (values IsNot Nothing AndAlso values("action") = "Index") Then
```

Comment: If Session is null how do I un-null it ? Can Session be null ? And btw the error is on the second test so why would it pass the first and not the second ?

Comment: If the first test is okay then your `Session` property is not null. In this case you can focus on the second test and check the property chain for nulls - this is pretty basic stuff I won't explain in here.